# Android Studio - "Unable to find explicit activity class" and I have already declared the activities in Manifest, which is the suggested problem

Tags: android, crash, function-declaration, explicit, activitynotfoundexception

This error comes up in the logcat when I try to click on a button in my application and it crashes:

````
```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.savedtrial, PID: 16090
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.savedtrial/com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2197)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1839)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5471)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5429)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:709)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5927)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5894)
    at com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:23)
    at com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$47nZOKobj58xqg2t-Q-x4Lw-Afk(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```
````

Here is my Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package = "com.example.savedtrial"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SAVEDTRIAL"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.savedtrial.contacting"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.savedtrial.Collab"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.savedtrial.notes"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.savedtrial.Calender"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.savedtrial.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Kotlin file with the button code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val actionBar = supportActionBar

        supportActionBar!!.setTitle("PROductivity")



        val calender: Button = findViewById(R.id.calender)

        calender.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, calender::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val notes: Button = findViewById(R.id.notes)

        notes.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, notes::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val contacting: Button = findViewById(R.id.contacting)

        contacting.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, contacting::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
    }
        val collab: Button = findViewById(R.id.collab)

        collab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, collab::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for one of the files that is supposed to show up when the its respective button is clicked (Just an action bar with back button)

```
package com.example.savedtrial

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class contacting : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacting)

        val actionBar = supportActionBar

        supportActionBar!!.setTitle("Contacting")

        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
}
```

My main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calender"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:text="Calender"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.021"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="Notes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.021"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.473" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contacting"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="Contacting"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.672" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/collab"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="Collab. Whiteboard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.019"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.844" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="PROductivity"
        android:textColor="#EA1616"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am new to Android Studio, so if possible, try not to delve into extremely complicated stuff, but don't worry if you have to - I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the error message is this part:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.savedtrial/com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton}

This means you passed a Button, not an Activity when you called `startActivity`. And indeed we can see this in your first `setOnClickListener`, where you refer to the wrong classes when constructing your intents:

```
val intent = Intent(this, calender::class.java)
```

You're using the `Button` instance named `calendar` for your class. It should be `Calendar` to match your manifest class - note the capital `C` to refer to your activity class, not your local variable:

```
val intent = Intent(this, Calender::class.java)
```

Similarly for every other click listener (except for maybe the `notes` activity, which you've also made lowercase, making it even harder to distinguish between a local variable and class name - you should always name your classes with a capital letter).

You'll find things much easier to understand if you separate the names of your variables from your class names. That's why you usually see classes named like `CalendarActivity`, `CollabActivity`, etc. where you can more easily determine what is an activity instance versus what is a button that starts that activity (`calendar`, `collab`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much ianhanniballake!
You literally saved my life, as well as giving me heavenly advice.
I really can't thank you enough for both the answer, and how it was almost instant!

Comment: Happy to help - best of luck going forward!